# executing Oracle stored procedures using ADO (c#)

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

Im trying to call a Oracle stored proc from a C# application using the following code

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
Recordset rs = new Recordset();
conn.Open("Provider=MSDAORA;User Id=username;Password=password;Data Source=DB;", null, null, 0); ;
rs.Open("sproc 'abc', 'xyz'", conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, -1);
```

where abc and xyz are input parameters..

However, I get "invalid SQL statement exception" when I try to run it..

Is there any other way to execute a oracle stored proc. I can execute MSSQL stored procs or normal Oracle queries in the same way described above..

I even tried using createparameter, but that didn't help either

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Grab the Oracle ODP.NET tools: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html

They are what I use to interact with our Oracle database from my ASP.NET application

[Check here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/procedures_plsql.htm#BABCCEGJ) for an example of calling an Oracle stored procedure in C#.

Basically, with the package:

```
// Create oracle command object for the stored procedure
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("HR_DATA.GETCURSORS", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// Enter a parameter for the procedure
OracleParameter dep_id = new OracleParameter();
dep_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
dep_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
dep_id.Value = 60;
cmd.Parameters.Add(dep_id);

// Add more parameters ... 

// Execute the stored procedure
```

[Here's a link to the API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/toc.htm)

Comment: +1. Microsoft has deprecated their own Oracle drivers, and recommends using Oracle's ODP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. Apparently I was missing brackets around input parameters...

Thanks,
Sam